# What would SEO and SEM initiatives be defined as?

Tags: seo, sem

I was asked to give examples of SEO or SEM initiatives, yet I really don't know what they mean by SEO or SEM initiatives.  Is this a strategy or method?  Sorry for sounding completely dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEO stands for Search Engine Optimization, while SEM stands for Search Engine Marketing. SEO would generally be considered to be "on-page" things like tweaking `title`'s and `h1` tags, but can also include things like link building. Generally SEO will be geared towards improving your organic search results.

Search Engine Marketing is usually used to describe paid advertisements on search engine's, such as Google Adwords. This would include things like improving landing pages and tweaking bids/budgets for Adwords campaigns to get the most value for your money.